# Pass username and password to a WebView

Tags: javascript, webview, jsx

I have an app where I have to log in using a username and a password. With that same username and password, I have a button that leads to a web page where I have a login form. How can I pass the username and password of the person who logged in on my app to the form on the web page?

My code looks like this:

```
import { StackScreenProps } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import React from 'react'
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';
import { useAuth } from '../hooks/useAuth';
import { RootStackParamList } from '../types';

export default function WebViewScreen({ navigation }: StackScreenProps<RootStackParamList, 'WebViewScreen'>) {
  const { email, password } = useAuth();

  const jsCode =
    `const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('username', email);
    formData.append('password', password);
    fetch('https://mylogin.page', {
      body: formData,
      method: 'POST'
    }).then(function (response) {
      console.log(response)
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.error(error)
    });`;

  return (
    <WebView
      source={{ uri: 'https://mylogin.page' }}
      injectedJavaScript={jsCode}
    />
  );
}
```

When I try it, nothing gets passed to my login form on my web page, so how can I archieve this? I have heard something about cookies based auth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this code:

```
import { StackScreenProps } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import React from 'react'
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';
import { useAuth } from '../hooks/useAuth';
import { RootStackParamList } from '../types';

export default function WebViewScreen({ navigation }: StackScreenProps<RootStackParamList, 'WebViewScreen'>) {
  const { email, password } = useAuth();

  const jsCode =
    `const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('username', ${email});
    formData.append('password', ${password});
    fetch('https://mylogin.page', {
      body: formData,
      method: 'POST'
    }).then(function (response) {
      alert("Hello! I am on success !!");
      console.log(response)
    }).catch((error) => {
     alert("Hello! I am on error !!");
      console.error(error)
    });`;

  return (
    <WebView
      source={{ uri: 'https://mylogin.page' }}
      injectedJavaScript={jsCode}
      javaScriptEnabled={true}
    />
  );
}
```